# Rolling (without slipping) ball on a moving surface 2

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, simulations, relative-motion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rolling (without slipping) ball on a moving surface](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47266/rolling-without-slipping-ball-on-a-moving-surface)

Apparently I didn't log in properly when I asked a question this morning: [Rolling (without slipping) ball on a moving surface](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47266/rolling-without-slipping-ball-on-a-moving-surface) and now I couldn't go back to leave comments. I am starting over here, so apologies for the confusion and inconvenience.

The user Raindrop left an answer to the above-mentioned question and I think he pointed out where I got confused. In the case where the surface (I am imagining more of a 2D arc swinging from side to side) is moving as the ball (appear as a simple circle) is rolling on it, the sum of force is not simply $F=ma=mgsinθ−f$, where $f$ is the frictional force acting on the ball. It was pointed out that I am missing the normal force. So here's my question: what is this normal force? I thought the normal force is what the surface exerts on the ball due to the gravitational force the ball is exerting on the surface. I thought the normal component of that force would be cancelled, leaving the $mgsinθ$ component only. Could someone explain that to me please?  Much appreciated.

Comment: I've merged your old (unregistered) account with your new one and you should have control of the original version of this question again.